# hide devise files and passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, devise, hide

I'm working on a rails app and to modify the layout of devise pages i used on the root of my rails application

```
rails g devise:views
```

so in the directory

```
app/views
```

i have all the files of the devise gem.

now that my work is ended i would like to hide those files again maintaining the modifies , how can i do it?

if you know even a way to only hide password it could also work

i didn't found any help in the README file for the plugins

Comment: It seems you want to do two opposite things. If you modified the devise files, removing them, will remove any changes you did. It kind of doesn't make sense.

Comment: Rafal is right. Why not not just put the files in a view/devise folder and update your routes etc.? Isn't there a chance you'll want to edit those layouts again in some way? Also, can you you clarify what you mean by "hide passwords"? How are the passwords visible?